# How to hide a div using uBlock by content somewhere in child tags

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, ublock-origin

There is a website that, researching through the browser's dev tools, has the following structure:

```
<div class='story_<<random_num>>'
  <header class=..
   <div class...
    .... some other nested open and closed tags, divs
    <a class=... href='/spam_url'>sponsor text</a>
...</div>
...
```

Is it possible to block or hide the entire root div class story... on a specific URL and/or link text like here sponsor_text?

I tried through block item in uBlock but the history number is either random or assigned as something from the database. The number of nested divs can be different as well as their classes, the only thing that is common is that somewhere inside there is definitely a sponsored link.

updated:

Below, I copied and pasted the site structure, deleted all the texts:

```html
<div class="stories-feed__container">

  <!--story_10453596_start-->
  <div class="story_10453596">
    <header class="story__header">
      <div class="story__labels">
        <a href="/companies" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"
           class="story__company-blog-badge company-blog-badge">Company Blog</a>
      </div>
      <h2 class="story__title"><a>...</a>
      </h2>
    </header>
    <div class="story__content-wrapper">
      <div class="story__tags tags">
        <a href="">...</a>
        <a href="" target="_blank"
           rel="noopener" class="tags__tag" data-tag-menu="true" data-tag="..."
           data-analytics-type="post_popup">...</a>
      </div>
      <div class="story__content story__typography" style="display: block">
        <div class="story__content-inner story__content-inner_slice-by-block">
          <div class="story-block story-block_type_text">
            <p>story... some text</p>
          </div>
          <div class="story-block story-block_type_image">
          </div>
          <!--story__cut-->
          <div class="story__hidden-blocks" style="">
            <div class="story-block story-block_type_text">
              <p>other text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="story__read-more">
              <span class="story__read-more-label"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--story_10453596_end-->

  </div>
  << other stories here>>
</div>
```

other articles have exactly the same structure, but they do not have a `<div class="story__labels">` block in the header in which the link to the resource

Comment: So the `<div class="story__labels">` is the indicator of a spam link that you want to block? Or is it some other section of the site code from your edit?

Comment: @TylerH 
yes, you are right. I have researched several regular and promotional articles, sometimes there is no cropping, sometimes additional decoration appears in the header:

    <header class="story_header">
    <div class=...
    <span....
    <svg...


but there is always a `<div class="story__labels">` block containing a link somewhere inside.

Is the task "to select a div containing somewhere inside another div with a class ..." is it easier?

Comment: In that case, yes in CSS you would use the new `:has()` selector, but the property is experimental (it's only at Working Draft stage in the CSS specification process, and some major browsers like Firefox simply don't support it at all yet (at least, not out-of-the-box)... I don't know if :has() will work/is supported in uBlock Origin, because it is both new and computationally expensive. At the very least, could you perhaps just block the spam link, instead of the entire article, by using `##.story__labels` as the filter?

Comment: @TylerH `<div class="story__labels">`contains only a link and a bit of article design, the main block with the text is located below, where I wrote `story... some text`  - these are the paragraphs before cut, and `other text` - main text with paragraphs  after cut. Need to block `<div class="story_10453596">` completely. `story__labels` with `<a href...` It's just the only way to tell the difference between an ordinary article and an advertising one

Comment: OK, yeah then in that case `:has()` is what you would need here. I'm not familiar enough with uBlock's filters to provide an answer, but this is their page for all those selectors, with detailed instructions on how to use them/what they support: https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Procedural-cosmetic-filters -- you can Ctrl+F and type in ":has" and jump straight to that section. I'll delete my answer as well since it addresses an older version of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should block all div elements with a class that begins with `story_` containing a div with a class of `story__labels`:

```
##div[class^='story_']:has(div.story__labels)
```

You could even be more explicit and include the header element if you wanted:

```
##div[class^='story_']:has(header > div.story__labels)
```

See here for more information: [Procedural cosmetic filters](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Procedural-cosmetic-filters#subjecthasarg)

Comment: That documentation is pretty dense. What if I'd want to block any div that contains a span with a given class whose text does not match a specific string?